# Make response based on "message"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to make a autoresponse for a chat, I do not know where to start.

The form data is;

```
{"channel":"#channel","message":"Hello","attributes":[{"type":"italic","start":0,"end":1},{"type":"color","start":0,"end":1,"color":128}],"token":"oausia9saUSiau98SsUASyuaysI","action":false,"request":"send"}
```

So whenever someone writes Hello, i want to response as message Hello how are you ?

i do not exactly know what language it must be written, and how should i code it to make the response ?

Comment: The answer is in your question's tags.

Comment: I'm a beginner what do you mean by that

Comment: oh yes but what should the codes would be to make the response

Comment: Use PHP for the server that somehow generates the answer, use the jQuery (a JavaScript framework) implementation of AJAX to load this answers dynamically.

Comment: @JohnSmith What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Daniel nothing yet i do not now how to declare the "message" so i can do something like if (message === 'Hi') do this

Comment: Well the example you gave us is a JSON-String. So you need to create an array with the values "channel", "message, "attributes", "token", "action" and "request" and pass it to "json_encode()" in PHP. But since you haven't provided any code I don't know where for example the "token" is coming from.

Comment: The "token" is the session_id for login, i don't have any coding yet and still don't understand how i work with the array( "channel", "message, "attributes", "token", "action", "request");
and how i could make it respond on message

Answer (score 1):

POST your form data to a php page something like this (either through ajax or regular form post):

```
<?php

$msg = strtolower($_POST['message']);

if($msg == 'hello'){
  echo 'Hello, how are you?';
  exit;
}
else if($msg == 'bye'){
  echo 'Good bye!';
  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Although the answer is very appreciated (+1 for the simple approach), I personally think there's no point in bumping these kind of questions: it clearly lacks research effort from the OP's part and it's too broad, general and has many different possible answers, e.g. json is not the only way to send ajax data between server and a client, php isn't the only server side language, etc.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working on message 'hello' i also tried to view it in console.log( 'Hello, how are you?'); and neither there havent reaction.

Comment: @arielnmz Agreed, thought it would help him get started :)

Comment: @JohnSmith as Sage said, it's an example to help you to *get started*, so based on his answer you can research more on server side form handling, ajax messages handling, json, string comparisons, trimming strings, etc.

Comment: @arielnmz i do know how to make it respond, i need to know how to fetch the "message" section so i can make based on the msg a respond!

Comment: That's exactly what I said. [json_decode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) ← First google result for *PHP read JSON*. Boy, you're not even trying.

Comment: That's what you think but i allready been there, but i don't get it maybe because i'm just a beginner. Don't think i'm experience like you ...;)

Comment: Uuhh what ? Why do you talk offtopic answer the question or leave..